# navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition throws Timeout error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-chrome, cordova, geolocation

I'm developing a cordova application that find a particular retailer on the map near to the user's current GPS coordinates. I used the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to get the user's current position and use the Google Maps API v3 javascript to do a text search to find the retailer on the map.

I have the standard and recommended settings in both Android and iOS config files, it works find on iOS but not on Android. I exported the APK file and installed on Moto G, the application name is listed in Settings -> Location -> Current Location Requests but the browser still throws Timeout error.

Any ideas what could be wrong and why unable to detect the current position?

**EDIT:** To add more info, sometime the application opens up and stays blank without any timeout alerts.

Comment: Anyone facing the same issues? Any recommended solutions? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You must add the geolocation plugin to your project using the following command. This sets the appropriate permissions in your platform config.xml file to allow the APK to speak with the OS:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

More: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did mention in my problem description that I have required `<uses-permissions>` in the AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml. however I'm using `navigator.geolocation` does that really require Cordova plugin to be installed, since its an HTML5 feature?